# Best practice of presenting running time results?

Tags: publications, graphics, tables

Often I come across the following situation: I have some experimental evaluation of running times of a new algorithm. Printing the running times in a table is good. Adding a plotted diagram illustrates the results in a nice way. Unfortunately this brings redundancy in a publication and needs many space, because the runnings times are already listed in the table.

Which way is best practice?

1. Only print a table (precise results, but no illustration)
2. Only print a plotted diagram (none precise results, but illustration)
3. Both (precise and illustration, but redundancy)

Comment: Are the times important in and of themselves ("wow, he got it in 2s") or scaling with some other parameter ("wow, it goes as ln N")? I would think the former would favor tables and the later favor plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for the diagram, supplemented by a short table if need be. But be prepared to have a "full version" (with complete tables as appendices or so) as a technical report or otherwise available for anyone who wants to replicate your work (or use your data for comparison, or whatever).

Comment: This is a perfect use for supplementary information in a journal publication.